# Attendence Points Rollover

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an attendance worksheet where we calculate employee attendance based on points, if employee absent they get 1 point and if tardy or did not complete shift get 1/2 points also if employee has perfect attendance during 90 days they get 1 points credit.

So far my worksheet works perfectly based on above criteria. Now I need to rollover points to next year, our attendance policy state at anniversary of employee point, they got last year point omitted. e.g. if they got point last year on 05/19/2014, this year will reduce that point.

I need formula which can check the last year date and if any employee has any points on same date last year reduce that point in this year.

[Link to the spreadsheet](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=38BDA6D9E9216FDA!641&authkey=!AJbEqGpu4Fhj58M&ithint=file%2Cxlsx)

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311157/track-attendance-by-point

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand your ultimate goal, but I think you can start by finding last year's date. So if today's date is 5/19/2015 and located in cell `A5` you would use the formula `=DATE(YEAR(A5)-1,MONTH(A5),DAY(A5))` to find one year prior or 5/19/2014. From there, you can use a `Vlookup`to see if there were any points last year. Assuming your spreadsheet was laid out like this (starting in cell A1) -

```
A        B       C       D 
1  5/18/2014     0      
2  5/19/2014     1      
3  5/20/2014     2      
4           
5  5/19/2015    5/19/2014
```

You would use this formula to do the lookup `=VLOOKUP(C5,$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)`. The result of the vlookup in this example will give you a 1. From there, you would use an `IF` formula or perhaps add or subtract to the 5/19/2015 value as needed.

Comment: did you check the attachment?

Comment: I don't see an attachment. However, I believe my solution will work.